# Provide the AWS PHP SDK with credentials via Symfony DotEnv

Tags: amazon-web-services, symfony, aws-sdk, dotenv, aws-php-sdk

In a Symfony 4.3 application using symfony/dotenv 4.3.11 and aws/aws-sdk-php 3.173.13:

I'd like to authenticate the AWS SDK using credentials provided via environment variables, and I'd like to use the dotenv component to provide those environment variables.

This should be possible: Setting the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables is one way to automatically authenticate the with the aws sdk. And DotEnv should turn your configuration into environment variables.

However, when I set these variables in my `.env.local` or `.env` files, I get the following error:

> Aws\Exception\CredentialsException: Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata service.

---

**This does not work:**

.env.local:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXX
```

```
$  ./bin/console command-that-uses-aws-sdk
```

**This works:**

```
$ AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXX ./bin/console command-that-uses-aws-sdk
```

**Debug info**:

I made a symfony command that outputs the environment variables in `$_ENV`. With AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/SECRET in .env.local, sure enough it appears as an environment variable:

```
...
    [SYMFONY_DOTENV_VARS] => MEQ_ENV,APP_ENV,APP_SECRET,DATABASE_URL,AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_REGION,AWS_ACCOUNT
    [AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID] => XXX
    [AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY] => XXXXXX
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [aws php client documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_environment.html) states:

> The SDK uses the getenv() function to look for the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN environment variables.

=> it uses `getenv()` not `$_ENV`.

But the Symfony Dotenv component (by default) just populates `$_ENV` and doesn't call `putenv` therefore your settings in .env files are not accessible by `getenv()`.

Here are some options:

1. call `Dotenv())->usePutenv(true)` (but as symfony states: Beware that `putenv()` is not thread safe, that's why this setting defaults to false)
2. call `putenv()` manually exclusively for the aws setting
3. Wrap the aws client in your own symfony service and inject the settings from .env